# Erro Xampp Windows 10 apache e mySQL não iniciam

Tags: xampp

Eu tenho o mySQL e SQL server instalado e tente instalar agora o Xampp, mas fico tento erros na hora de iniciar o Apache e Mysql, já tentei trocar as portas e sem sucesso.

error.log

```
 [Wed Nov 08 15:30:35.891547 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3644:tid 212] AH01909: 
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
matches the server name
[Wed Nov 08 15:30:36.196082 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3644:tid 212] AH01909: 
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
 matches the server name
 [Wed Nov 08 15:30:36.669476 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3644:tid 212] 
 AH00455: Apache/2.4.28 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.0.24 configured -- 
 resuming normal operations
 [Wed Nov 08 15:30:36.669476 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3644:tid 212] 
 AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct  4 2017 11:36:32
[Wed Nov 08 15:30:36.669476 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3644:tid 212] AH00094: 
 Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Nov 08 15:30:36.685101 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3644:tid 212] 
 AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10664
[Wed Nov 08 15:30:37.200207 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10664:tid 216] AH01909: 
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
 matches the server name
[Wed Nov 08 15:30:37.455629 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10664:tid 216] AH01909: 
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
matches the server name
 [Wed Nov 08 15:30:37.479692 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10664:tid 216] 
  AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

[image: erro]

Comment: Tive alguns problemas com o XAMPP também, a solução mais comum é reinstala-lo. Lembrando que ele funciona sendo executado como administrador.

Comment: Questões de configuração de serviços, aplicações e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su], [sf], [unix.se] ou mesmo no [devops.se] conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Mais detalhes na [help].